# How much time is needed to "get back to shape" after a long period of time without singing?

Tags: practice, voice

For example, if one goes without cycling for 5 years or even decades, he can get back to speed pretty much within an hour, maybe two.

For drum and piano, it may be longer, maybe a month or two.

What about singing?

How much time on average (coarse estimate) will an established singer take to "pick up the skills again" after a long time without practicing?

Comment: What? A competitive cyclist will not be back anywhere near their previous levels of performance if they don't cycle for several years without significant practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's very much an individual thing - two people with the same amount of experience and the same length of hiatus will take different amounts of time to get back into the swing of things.

With the voice in particular it depends what they've been up to in the mean time. If they've been singing a little at home, doing occasional vocal exercises, and keeping fairly fit, they'll probably be able to reach their previous level fairly quickly. If, on the other hand, they haven't been looking after their voice at all, been smoking & drinking heavily for example, it may take their voice longer to reach peak condition.

As with anything, there are always exceptions to these rules of thumb - but by and large I think  most vocalists would be back on form after a couple of weeks of practising.